# Apple iPad Wifi 2017

Tags: applications, macos

How Do I delete apps with the new iOS 11 update? I does not allow me to delete the app when I hold it down and it wiggles

Answer (score 1):

Hold down on an app icon until it starts to wiggle and an x mark appears on the upper left of the application icon. All icons should display this behavior. Apps without an x cannot be deleted using this method. Press the x to delete the app.